# Angular2 - creating multiple variable declarations in component class vs directly using object in template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-template

I have a component which retrieves a large nested object from an http request. Within my component class, I declare hundreds of variables that extrapolate data from that object and those properties are then interpolated within its template.

This has resulted in my component class having hundreds of lines of code simply from those properties being declared and assigned. Would be better to just use the object itself within the template?  The following is an example to demonstrate:

Let's say I have a really large and nested **cuisines** object that's coming in from a service.  With my current approach, within the component class, I declare variables for the individual properties that I need:

`let italianBreakfast = cuisine.data.breakfast.italian;
 let ...
 let ...
 let ...`

This is then interpolated within the template: `<div>{{italianBreakfast}}</div>`

My revised strategy is to simply use the object in the template:

`<div>{{cuisine.data.breakfast.italian}}</div>`

In doing so, the text between the curly brackets in my templates get larger, but I would gain in that I'm no longer declaring properties to store object values in my component class, which would result in saving hundreds of lines of code.  Which would be better and is there a best practice around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create smaller components inside this large component and pass them specific parts of the `cuisines` object as `@Input` properties.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do that.  Are there any disadvantages to referencing object properties using the object within my template?

Comment: I wouldn't say there are disadvantages. In my opinion, this approach is better than declaring hundreds of variables. It's just about how big that object is and how deeply nested properties will you use in the template and is this affecting readability. Why can't you use smaller components, though?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Can't create smaller component b/c it's not my project :)